# Regular Expression To Remove Unicode Characters From Json File Not Working

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have a json file that contains url links and uncode characters.. I want to clean the data before doing text analysis. I have sucessfully remove url links; however, I can't remove unicode, which usually starts with "\u...." followed by four letter, numbers or combination of both. the regular expression for that I tested in sublime and seems to work by removing all unicode, except when I use in python, it is still printing the weired characters on the terminal... which in this case is the smily face '\uD83E\uDD2A' but in the terminal shows up as [?].. how can I remove this in python using reg expression. any help appreciated. Note: the content of data is a list containing twitter (json) data I downloaded of my tweet history through a twitter service they provide.

```
RT @RobertDeNiroUS: i want to watch the final game...  https://someurl https://someurl
```

here's what I'm using

```
for t in range(5):
    tweet = re.sub(r"\\u....", "", data[t]['full_text'])
    tweet = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", tweet)
    print(tweet)
```

Comment: What's in `data`? Please show how you set this variable.

Comment: @lenz a list of json elements... but I think is irrelevant. I print the text above which is tweet

Comment: It's relevant to know if you called `json.load()` on the JSON elements.

Comment: Because if you properly deal with JSON data in Python, you usually don't have to deal with escape sequences like `"\\uD83e\\udd2a"`, but instead you get the characters decoded as `""`, which is the same as `"\U0001f92a"`.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] like @lenz mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode is defined as any code point  greater than or equal to  x100.

The Python regex  for  `UTF- 8 / 32   Unicode Ranges using \uXXXX \UXXXXXXXX syntax` is :

`[\u0100-\uFFFF\U00010000-\U0010FFFF]+`

https://regex101.com/r/1YUSng/1

**________________________**

If for Python, should ever need the UTF-16 one for surrogates, it is :

`(?:[\u0100-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|[\uDC00-\uDFFF](?<![\uD800-\uDBFF}][\S\s]))+`

Comment: It works I was using "\u..." for regex but that leaves anything greater than 4 chars

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how to do this in Python, but here is how I did it in JavaScript. May be the same `replace` function works in Python too

```js
'use strict'

const str1 = 'test\uD83E\uDD2Astring';

let result =  str1.replace(/([^ -~]+)/g, '');
console.log(`the result1 is ${result}`);
```

and the result is 
`the result1 is teststring`

I used this [link](https://bytefreaks.net/programming-2/javascript/javasript-remove-all-non-printable-and-all-non-ascii-characters-from-text). Please go over it and check if you need some more clarifications.

If this does not help you solve your problem, I am happy to delete this answer.

Comment: Yeah this won't work exactly in Python. `str.replace` doesn't use regex, but `re.sub` does. Also Python doesn't have regex literals.

Comment: so you can't plug `/([^ -~]+)/g` in `re.sub`?

Comment: You would use a plain string for the regex: `'([^ -~])+'`. And the `g`lobal flag is implied.

Comment: use re.sub(r"regex", "substitute", string) .. don't use string.replace()